# Display a popup when a PHP condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having the following project that I have been working with for a while. Everything is working fine as you can see after running the snnipets.

```css
/* The dark background behind the dialogs */

.dialog-overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    z-index: 10;
}

/* The dialogs themselves */

.dialog-card{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 570px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -285px;
    top: 50%;

    font: bold 14px sans-serif;

    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:  #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding: 45px 50px;
}

.dialog-card .dialog-question-sign{
    float: left;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:  #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 68px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color:  #b4d8f3;
}

.dialog-card .dialog-info{
    float: left;
    max-width: 350px;
}

.dialog-card h5{ /* Dialog title */
    color:  #383c3e;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 5px 0 30px;
}

.dialog-card p{  /* Dialog text */
    color:  #595d60;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 21px;

    margin: 30px 0;
}

.dialog-card .dialog-confirm-button,
.dialog-card .dialog-reject-button{
    font-weight: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding: 12px 40px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
}

.dialog-card .dialog-confirm-button{
    background-color:  #87bae1;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.dialog-card .dialog-reject-button{
    background-color:  #e4749e;
}

.dialog-card button:hover{
    opacity:0.96;
}

.dialog-card button:active{
    position:relative;
    bottom:-1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-confirm-dialog" class="dialog-overlay">

        <div class="dialog-card">

            <div class="dialog-question-sign"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>

            <div class="dialog-info">

                <h5>Are you sure?</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pharetra id odio a pellentesque. In dapibus maximus augue, eu dapibus felis laoreet non.</p>

                <button class="dialog-confirm-button">Yes</button>
                <button class="dialog-reject-button">No</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


<span class="dialog-show-button" data-show-dialog="my-confirm-dialog">Show Confirm Dialog</span>

    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        // This is an example jQuery snippet that makes the dialogs work

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // We have two control functions that show or hide dialogs

            function showDialog(id){

                // Find the dialog and show it

                var dialog = $('#' + id),
                        card = dialog.find('.dialog-card');

                dialog.fadeIn();

                // Center it on screen

                card.css({
                    'margin-top' : -card.outerHeight()/2
                });

            }

            function hideAllDialogs(){

                // Hide all visible dialogs
                $('.dialog-overlay').fadeOut();

            }

            // Here is how to use these functions

            $('.dialog-confirm-button, .dialog-reject-button').on('click', function () {

                // Hide the dialog when the confirm button is pressed
                hideAllDialogs();

            });

            $('.dialog-overlay').on('click', function (e) {

                if(e.target == this){
                    // If the overlay was clicked/touched directly, hide the dialog
                    hideAllDialogs();
                }


            });

            $(document).keyup(function(e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    // When escape is pressed, hide all dialogs

                    hideAllDialogs();
                }

            });


            // Here, we are listening for clicks on the "show dialog" buttons,
            // and showing the correct dialog

            $('.dialog-show-button').on('click', function () {

                // Take the contents of the  "data-show-dialog" attribute
                var toShow = $(this).data('show-dialog');

                showDialog(toShow);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Beside being able to display the popup after clicking on `Show Confirm Dialog`, I want to be able to display the popup when a `PHP condition` is met.
Like:

```
if(condition){

  //Display Popup

}
```

Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: The correct answer to this question very much depends on whether the condition is known to be met when the page is loaded (in which case the answers given below will suffice) or if the action of the user would change the result after the page is loaded (in which case you would need to send an ajax request back to the server to do the PHP check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing the php should be in the same script as the html, js, ...:

```
<?php
if(1===1) {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');";
    echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

this needs to live at the very end of your html, otherwise it'll fail, because DOM not loaded, etc...

To be sure you could place that inside `$(document).ready`:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
       // leave the function-definitions and eventlisteners here
       //...

       // add at the very end:
       <?php 
       if(1===1) {
           echo "showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');";
       }
       ?>

 });
 </script>
```

Another solution would be to only set a js-var depending on the php-condition, and check for that in js.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I see you could achieve this is just make a script tag in which you would call this function.

```
<?php if( condition ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        showDialog(id)
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some value from PHP in JavaScript, you have to put it somewhere on the page with PHP and read it with JavaScript.
A dirty inline-script solution would be something like this:

```
<script>
  var myValueFromPhp = <?= \json_encode($anyThing) ?>;
</script>
```

A clean solution depends on the use-case, but would be similar:

```
<div data-coolness="<?='yepp'?>></div>
```

(or something like that, depending on the templating engine)